# error email already exists

Tags: javascript, php, email

I got this code from someone here from stack overflow I copied it and I tried it out but I doesn't work the way I want it to if I put an already existing email address from my database it gives an error saying email address already taken please choose another email. but when I submit an email address that is not in the database it still displays the same error how can this be fixed

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 
$('#submit').click(function() {alert("Email already exists. Please choose a different email");
var emailVal = $('#email').val(); // assuming this is a input text field

$.post('checkemail.php', {'email' : emailVal}, function(data) {
  if (data == 1)
  { 
     $("#registration").submit();
  }
 else
  {

      return false;
  }

 });
 });});
 </script>

  </head>
 <body>

 <form id="registration" name="registration" method="post" action="profile1.php">
 <p>email
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
 </p>
 <p>
 <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
 </p>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the php code

```
<?php
include("con.php");

$sql = "SELECT email FROM registered_d WHERE email = " .$_POST['email'];
$select = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);

   if (mysqli_num_rows > 0) {
  echo "0"; // email exists
 }else{
  echo "1"; // email doesn't exists
 return;}
?>
```

can someone help me solve this

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_num_rows` is a function and therefore should be used as such — `myseli_num_rows($select)`.

Also keep in mind that using `$_POST['email']` in `SQL` query unescaped is a bad and dangerous practice.

And why `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` if you don't know whether you have any?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `alert("Email already exists. Please choose a different email");` when the submit button is pressed. This produces the alert every time no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').click(function() {alert("Email already exists. Please choose a different email");
```

This will show an alert with the message that an email already exists every time the submit button is clicked. You need to move this, like the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var emailVal = $('#email').val(); // assuming this is a input text field

        $.post('checkemail.php', {'email' : emailVal}, function(data) {
            if(data=='exist') {
                alert("Email already exists. Please choose a different email");
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#registration').submit();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the error is not showing even though I submitted the same email address as in the database

Comment: Is your condition `if (data=='exist')` correct? I just copied the code you already had and moved the alert for an email that already exists to inside the check you already had. Try `console.log(data)` in the `post` callback to see what comes back. It looks like you're returning `0` or `1`, not '' or 'exist'.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 
        $('#submit').click(function() {

            var emailVal = $('#email').val(); // assuming this is a input text field
            $.post('checkemail.php', {'email' : emailVal}, function(data) {
                if(data.message == "exist")
                    alert("This email address already exists");
                else
                    $('#registration').submit();
            });

            return false;
        });
    </script>



        </head>
        <body>

         <form id="registration" name="registration" method="post" action="profile1.php">
         <p>email
         <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
         </p>
         <p>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
         </p>
         </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

In your php code

```
<?php
include("con.php");

$sql = "SELECT email FROM registered_d WHERE email = " .$_POST['email'];
$select = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($select) > 0) {
   echo json_encode(array("message"=>"exist"));
 }
 else echo  echo json_encode(array("message"=>"notexist"));
?>
```

Comment: the same error is shown either way and it allows the page to submit even though the email is the same

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "mysqli_num_rows" is a variable and may not be the result of the fetch. The $row *is* the result, so perhaps you should check that for the condition instead.

According to this, rows should be an array:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Something like this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($rows) > 0) {
  echo "exist";
}else echo 'notexist';
```